# Magento custom block. Can't get block's file

Tags: php, xml, magento, module, block

I'm trying to create a new custom block module.
/app/code/local/TutsPlus/Demo/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<gllobal>
    <models>
        <demo>
            <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Model</class>
        </demo>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <demo><class>TutsPlus_Demo_Block</class></demo>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <demo>
            <class>TutsPlus_Demo_Helper</class>
        </demo>
    </helpers>
    <events>
        <demo>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>demo/observer/</class>
            <method>logCustomer</method>
        </demo>
    </events>
</gllobal>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <tutsplus_demo>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>TutsPlus_Demo</module>
                <frontName>demo</frontName>
            </args>
        </tutsplus_demo>
        <catalog>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <demo before="Mage_Catalog">TutsPlus_Demo</demo>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </catalog>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <demo>
                <file>tutsplus.xml</file>
            </demo>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

/app/code/local/TutsPlus/Demo/Block/Configurable.php

```
class TutsPlus_Demo_Block_Configurable extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    public function getConfigurableProducts() {
        return 'it works';
    }
}
```

/app/code/local/TutsPlus/Demo/controllers/config.xml

```
    class TutsPlus_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
public function configurableAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

configurable.phtml

```
<?php
echo 'zzz';
echo $this->getConfigurableProducts();
```

tutsplus.xml

```
<layout>
    <tutsplus_demo_index_configurable>
        <reference name="content">
            <!--<block type="page/html" name="demo" template="tutsplus/configurable.phtml" />-->
            <block type="tutsplus_demo/configurable" name="demo_configurable" template="tutsplus/configurable.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </tutsplus_demo_index_configurable>
</layout>
```

When I use commented line I heve just "zzz", no result of working function  getConfigurableProducts. If I use second line I have nothing and file haven't been included.

**EDIT 1** My folder structure

[image: my folder structure]

[image: template structure]

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in tutsplus.xml

```
<layout>
<tutsplus_demo_index_configurable>
    <reference name="content">
        <!--<block type="page/html" name="demo" template="tutsplus/configurable.phtml" />-->
        <block type="demo/configurable" name="demo_configurable" template="tutsplus/configurable.phtml" />
    </reference>
</tutsplus_demo_index_configurable>
```

Remove following code from your config.xml

```
  <events>
    <demo>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>demo/observer/</class>
        <method>logCustomer</method>
    </demo>
</events>
```

Refresh cache and storage and check it.

Comment: Hi saumik! Still the same result. Cache refreshed. `code`print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());`code`   - Array ( [0] => default [1] => STORE_default [2] => THEME_frontend_default_tutsplus [3] => tutsplus_demo_index_configurable [4] => customer_logged_out )

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know what exactly action is assigned to layout handle, you can "debug" layout handles.

Please paste these code between

```
    $this->loadLayout();
    print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
    $this->renderLayout();
```

You will see assigned layout handles to controller